# Método duplica el registro, debería hacer merge - CrudRepository Java/Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, crud, testing

Estoy generando un serial con el meptodo que expongo abajo. Debe crearse el registro si no existe el prefijo en la tabla, y si existe, incremetar el count y hacer el merge. Estoiy usnado CrudRepository donde se supone el save hace un update si hace match con algún registro

```java
...
    
        @Transactional
        public String generateSerialNumber(String prefix) {
    
            Optional<Counter> existingCounterOpt = counterRepository.findByPrefix(prefix);
    
            Counter counter;
    
            if (existingCounterOpt.isPresent()) {
                System.out.println("paso por el if que indica que existe");
                counter = existingCounterOpt.get();
                counter.setCount(counter.getCount() + 1);
            } else {
                counter = new Counter();
                counter.setPrefix(prefix.toUpperCase());
                counter.setCount(1);
            }
            counterRepository.save(counter);
    
            return String.format("%s-%05d", prefix.toUpperCase(), counter.getCount());
        }
    
    }
```

Comparto también el test

```java
  
    @DataJpaTest
    @AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)
    @Transactional
    public class SerialNumberTest {
    
        @Autowired
        TestEntityManager entitymanager;
    
        @Autowired
        SerialNumberGenerator serialNumberGenerator;
    
        @Autowired
        CounterAdapterImpl counterAdapterImpl;
...
    
        @Test
        public void findSerialNumberExiting() {
    
            try {
                Counter conuter = new Counter();
                conuter.setId(1l);
                conuter.setPrefix("COLSO");
                conuter.setCount(6);
                entitymanager.merge(conuter);
    
                String serial1 = serialNumberGenerator.generateSerialNumber("COLSO");
    
                String serial2 = serialNumberGenerator.generateSerialNumber("COLSO");
                System.out.println(serial2);
    
                assertThat(serial1).isEqualTo(serial2);
    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error" + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    
   
    }
```

Me da un error por duplicado cuando intento guardar el serial2. El save está haciendo un insert y no un update. ¿cómo puedo solucionar este caso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías usar `orElseGet()` en lugar de `isPresent()`

```
@Transactional
public String generateSerialNumber(String prefix) {
    Counter counter = counterRepository.findByPrefix(prefix)
        .orElseGet(() -> {
            Counter newCounter = new Counter();
            newCounter.setPrefix(prefix.toUpperCase());
            newCounter.setCount(1);
            return newCounter;
        });

    counter.setCount(counter.getCount() + 1);
    counterRepository.save(counter);

    String formattedPrefix = prefix.toUpperCase();
    return String.format("%s-%05d", formattedPrefix, counter.getCount());
}
```